# Outlook 2010 C# Capturing event on quick category select

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to trigger an event, where a user updates a mail with a quick category select.

[image]

I have tried PropertyChange and it only works when inspecting the mail(double clicking on it to view the mail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are subscribing to the source mail item only when an inspector window is opened. You need to track the selected item in the Explorer window to be able to catch the `PropertyChange` event for such cases.

The [Explorer.SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) event is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. This event also occurs when the user (either programmatically or via the user interface) clicks or switches to a different folder that contains items, because Outlook automatically selects the first item in that folder.

```
Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer  

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer  
End Sub  

Private Sub myOlExp_SelectionChange()  
 MsgBox myOlExp.Selection.Count & " items selected."  
End Sub
```